# Symfony2 - integration of ckeditor and sonata media bundle

Tags: symfony, ckeditor

I am trying to integarte IvoryCKEditor with sonata media bundle. Perpose is to allow image uploads in ckeditor. I tried it using a CoopTilleulsCKEditorSonataMediaBundle but i keep getting an error:

*An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Unable to generate a URL for the named route "admin_sonata_media_media_ckeditor_browser" as such route does not exist.") in "IvoryCKEditorBundle:Form:ckeditor_widget.html.twig".*

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You should check your routes with the command:

```
$ php app/console debug:router | grep ckeditor
```

Then you have to replace `admin_sonata_media_media_ckeditor_browser` and `admin_sonata_media_media_ckeditor_upload` by routes founded with this command, in the config of ivory_ck_editor (maybe in your `config.yml` or your `ivory_ckeditor.yml` file)

If you don't have route for ckeditor, I think you should check if you install correctly the bundle.

Answer (score 1):

1) install SonataFormatterBundle 2) add the bundle and its dependencies in AppKernel 3) config files 4) CLEAR CACHE 5) roll

Comment: **php bin/console cache:clear** is required for this. I wasted 1 hr after installed sonata formatter bundle with no route found error with `admin_sonata_media_media_ckeditor_browser` this route. After read your answer and cleared cache. it's working for me. Thanks a lot @roelleor

Answer (score 1):

### Reason of the issue

> This problem arises when trying to integrate CKEditor through the
>   SonataFormatterBundle without using the SonataAdminBundle.

In fact, the integration proposed by the SonataFormatterBundle is meant to only work for the SonataAdminBundle, and no easy integration for a custom admin bundle is currently available.

> **Note that this dependency is  not specified in the documentation at the moment.**

### How to solve the problem

Simply install the SonataAdminBundle following [this installation process](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/3-x/doc/getting_started/installation.html). You **do** need to configure the bundle **entirely** as specified in the documentation. To add the routes that were missing, such as `admin_sonata_media_media_ckeditor_browser`, simply add the following to your `config/routes.yml`:

```
# This is your custom admin bundle
admin:
    resource: "@AdminBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /admin/

# Import SonataAdminBundle routes
admin_area:
    resource: "@SonataAdminBundle/Resources/config/routing/sonata_admin.xml"
    prefix: /admin/sonata # put whatever prefix here

_sonata_admin:
    resource:   .
    type:       sonata_admin
    prefix:     /admin
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add something.

If you are SURE that you have installed, all dependencies, and set all configs correctly, and still getting this error, then the cause may be that you have defined your 'sonata_media' prefix in routing.yml differently.

You can check all urls in your project in:

```
 app/cache/dev/appDevUrlGenerator.php
```

In there you will find ALL routes in a variable `$declaredRoutes`

Afterwards simply put correct route name for browsing.

Answer (score 0):

It will not work without SonataMediaBundle - you will need to install it with SonataFormatterBundle

Sonata become too complicated as for me, so I just use IvoryCKEditorBundle directly